# Active master not accepting new applications if one of the masters added to zookeeper is down

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, bigdata, apache-zookeeper, high-availability

I am facing a very weird issue while enabling high availability(HA) in spark stand alone cluster.

I have configured 3 spark masters and registered them in zookeeper by following below steps:

1. Create a configuration file `ha.conf` with the content as follows:

> spark.deploy.recoveryMode=ZOOKEEPER
>
> spark.deploy.zookeeper.url=ZK_HOST:2181
>
> spark.deploy.zookeeper.dir=/spark

2. start all 3 masters by passing this property file as argument to start-master script as below:

> ./start-master.sh -h localhost -p 17077 --webui-port 18080
>   --properties-file ha.conf

this way I got all 3 spark master started and registered in zookeeper.

**Working**
If I kill the active master then all the running application gets picked up by the new active master.

**Not Working**
If any one spark master(for eg: localhost:17077) is down/not working and I submit an application using the below command:

> ./bin/spark-submit --class WordCount --master spark://localhost:17077,h2:27077,h3:37077 --deploy-mode cluster --conf spark.cores.max=1 ~/TestSpark-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /user1/test.txt

Ideally that should go to the active master and should work fine because only one master is down and others are working but I am getting exception as:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.Client$$anonfun$7.apply(Client.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.Client$$anonfun$7.apply(Client.scala:230)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.Client$.main(Client.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.Client.main(Client.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:736)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:17077
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:228)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:179)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:197)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:191)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:187)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:17077
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:224)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:289)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
        ... 1 more
```

Any help/clue/suggestion is appreciated. Please help me understand this, I have searched for problems like this but could not find anything.

**UPDATE**

I am facing this problem when I submit the application in cluster mode and there's no problem if I submit the application in client mode.

Comment: anyone have any idea about this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application can be submitted to spark rest server which runs on 6066 rather then submitting on legacy system runs on 7077.

So the issue got fixed when application is submitted to rest server using the below command:

```
./bin/spark-submit --class WordCount --master spark://localhost:6066,h2:6066,h3:6066 --deploy-mode cluster --conf spark.cores.max=1 ~/TestSpark-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /user1/test.txt
```

Now if one spark master is down then application gets submitted to the other spark master.